# React anchor element not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

When I make an h1 element in react going to the root div and try to add something else to the root div it doesn't add the h1 and adds the other thing. I have tried using another div but it did not work. I tried it outside and inside the root div but still no luck.

My Code(this is the react.html file, index.html has no react)

```html
<html>
    <body style="font-size: 2rem; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">
        <div id="root"> <div id="linkdv"></div></div>
       
    </body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script>
        const rootEl = document.getElementById('root')
        const linkdv = document.getElementById("linkdiv")
        const element = React.createElement('h1', { id:'header'}, 'Hey There This Is Using React')
        const link = React.createElement('a', { href:'index.html'}, 'Second Page') 
        ReactDOM.render(element, rootEl)
        ReactDOM.render(link, rootEl)
        
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Keep me posted as to whether the answer adequately solves your problem, or if you're still facing issues with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render):

> ReactDOM.render() controls the contents of the container node you pass in. **Any existing DOM elements inside are replaced when first called.** Later calls use React’s DOM diffing algorithm for efficient updates.

Because your `linkdv` element is a child of your `root` element, it gets wiped out when writing to your `root` element. That's why adding the second element didn't help. You're also not rendering to your `linkdv` right now anyway, you're rendering to `root` twice. Furthermore, you're not correctly selecting `linkdv` - you're using the wrong id. So if you change your code to this:

```html
<html>
    <body style="font-size: 2rem; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">
        <div id="root"></div>
        <div id="linkdv"></div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script>
        const rootEl = document.getElementById('root')
        const linkdv = document.getElementById("linkdv")
        const element = React.createElement('h1', { id:'header'}, 'Hey There This Is Using React')
        const link = React.createElement('a', { href:'index.html'}, 'Second Page') 
        ReactDOM.render(element, rootEl)
        ReactDOM.render(link, linkdv)
    </script>
</html>
```

Then your code will at least render your elements to the page. However, it's not usually advisable to call `ReactDOM.render()` multiple times, as [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#updating-the-rendered-element) states:

> In practice, most React apps only call ReactDOM.render() once.

You likely only want to render a single time to the `root` element, and you'd define your element hierarchy/attributes in JSX (using Babel as a transpiler). That also allows you to easily nest elements you want to render, if that's what you're going for here. Take a look at [Introducing JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) to get started with that.

If you're not using Node to manage your toolchain and build your project, you can get Babel from https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js, which will allow you to use JSX in your code. Here's [an example](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/create-a-standalone-react-app/) of how to use it.

Comment: could you give me the cdn for babel and jsx?

Comment: @SomeOneOnEarthWhoLives Sure, I've edited my answer accordingly.